# One form to write more POCO classes in a code-first database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm learning c# language and, after reading a specific manual, i'm trying to write an application, this application will write data in a sql server CE database. I've made a code-first approach, so i started writing domains classes and at the first data-access the SDF file   create succefully the database.
My problem is related to some inherited classes. I've a situation like this

```
  public class Fruit
  {
    //some properties here
  }

  public class Orange: Fruit { }
  public class Apple: Fruit { }

//...

  public class AAContext : DbContext
  {
    public AAContext()
      : base("name=AAdata")
    {
    }
        public DbSet<Orange> Oranges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Apple> Apples { get; set; }

        // other code...
  }
```

I've made this because if I use one class (Fruit) to registry more that one entity, compiler say to me that this is not possible

Now, when I'm writing code in a winform (one single form to make data entry for all Fruit class) to read/modify data in/from every table, so i must bind datagrid and fields from code; and for append/delete data I don't know how to access the DbSet registered (Oranges and Apples) or how to pass them to the form as a parameter of the constructor. I've done some experiment, my results are:

I can't pass (to the form constructor) directly an objet `DbSet<Fruit>`, it return a cast error, so...
I can pass an `IEnumerable<Fruit>` (parameter to the constructor (using covariance) and i can assign this to the datasource of a grid, and it works. But...
how can I add/delete/modify data?

So, my question is: how can I bind winform controls and how can I perform database operations WITHOUT know from the start wich particular class (Orange or Apple) inherited from a base class (Fruit) I want to use?

From the start my intention was was to write code (for example) for a button (in a MainForm)

```
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  dbConn = new DataLayer.AAContext();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var fruitArchive = dbConn.Apples;
  var newWindow = new ArchiveForm(fruitArchive , "Apple's archive");
  newWindow.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

and the ArchiveForm with the overloaded contructor...

```
public ArchiveForm(DbSet<DataLayer.Fruit> domainClass, string Title)
  : this()
{
  dataGridView.DataSource = domainClass.ToList();
  this.Text = Title;
}
```

and save domainClass inside the ArchiveForm to use it to add, remove, modify data treating it like a `DbSet<Fruit>` or something else similar

I know that is impossible in THIS form, how can I do it?